# JAVASCRIPT - Acessando propriedade que contém link de api

Tags: javascript, api, request

Boa noite! não consigo acessar a propriedade title dentro da films como faço para fazer essa requisição?

> Planeta: Hoth
>
> População total: unknown
>
> Clima: frozen
>
> Terreno: tundra, ice caves, mountain ranges
>
> Aparição em filmes: https://swapi.co/api/films/2/

esse é o retorno que tenho da requisição porém queria retornar o nome dos filmes em questão. já dei uma pesquisada aqui e em outros foruns mas não consegui resolver ainda. caso alguém possa me ajudar fico grato. vlw rapaziada!

código:

```
function getPlanet() {
    let randomNumber = Math.floor(( Math.random() * 10 ) + 1 )
    let apiUrl = 'https://swapi.co/api/planets/' + randomNumber

        // integrando API para adicionar a função getPlanet;
    axios.get (apiUrl).then(( function ( response ) {        
      updateInfo (response.data)

    } )) 

}

    function updateInfo(data) {   

                name.innerText = 'Planeta: ' + data.name;
                population.innerText = 'População total: ' + data.population;
                climate.innerText = 'Clima: ' + data.climate;
                terrain.innerText = 'Terreno: ' + data.terrain;    
                films.innerText = 'Aparição em filmes: ' + data.films.title;
        }

            // Evento Click;
    button.addEventListener('click', getPlanet);
```

Comment: Não entendi. Você está fazendo a requisição para `https://swapi.co/api/films` ou para `https://swapi.co/api/planets`? Onde no seu código você acessa essa propriedade `title` que eu não estou vendo?

Comment: Então. eu faço a requisição para planets, e dentro dessa planets tem a propriedade 'films' que me retorna um link de api e dentro dessa api tem a propriedade title que retorna o nome dos filmes em que esse determinado planeta apareceu. " films.innerText = 'Aparição em filmes: ' + data.films.title;" desculpe por não ter editado corretamente o meu código. vlw pelo feed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode utilizar `async`? Considerando que você está utilizando `let` acredito que compatibilidade com IE não é prioridade, então vamos lá.

Dentro da resposta da rota `/planets`, você possui a propriedade `films` que é um array com as urls para buscar mais informações desses filmes. Não adianta tentar acessar a propriedade `title` dessa url, a url em si é só uma string, você precisa fazer a requisição para elas também.

```
async function getPlanet() {
    let randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1)
    let apiUrl = 'https://swapi.co/api/planets/' + randomNumber

    // integrando API para adicionar a função getPlanet;
    let planet = await axios.get(apiUrl)
    let films = await Promise.all(
        planet.data.films.map(film => axios.get(film))
    )

    let planetData = planet.data
    let filmsData = films.map(film => film.data)

    updateInfo(planetData, filmsData)
}
```

Agora sim você tem de fato a resposta da rota `/films`. Não se esqueça que `films` é um array, se você quiser a propriedade `title` do primeiro filme, terá que usar `films[0].data.title` ou no caso do exemplo, `filmsData[0].title`:

```
function updateInfo(planetData, filmsData) {
    let titles = filmsData.map(filmData => filmData.title)

    name.innerText = 'Planeta: ' + planetData.name;
    population.innerText = 'População total: ' + planetData.population;
    climate.innerText = 'Clima: ' + planetData.climate;
    terrain.innerText = 'Terreno: ' + planetData.terrain;
    films.innerText = 'Aparição em filmes: ' + titles.join(', ');
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado de verdade pela ajuda. sou novo com javascript e to aprendendo muito aqui no forum, vlw!!